# Assigning priority to the tasks

Tags: java, task, scheduling, cloudsim

What are the factors to be considered to assign the priority for the tasks?

I am using CloudSim 3.0.3 simulator for simulation where I need to assign the priority for each task before the execution and deploy the tasks based on the priority. I have the following parameters for each task:

- Time for Execution(Approximate)
- File Size
- Output size
- No of processing elements(PEs) needed for execution.

I am going to deploy the tasks on a Virtual Machine that has the following:

- Amount of storage space
- RAM
- MIPS
- PEs
- Bandwidth

What parameters should I need to consider for assigning priority for the tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `time for execution` as the main parameter or the `output size` to assign priority for the tasks.

The tasks with **high output size** and the execution time will get higher priority.

Now, also assign priority to the available VMs according to its **remaining resource(CPU, RAM, MIPS)** where **more available resource** will get high priority.

Now, you can assign the task with high priority to the VM with high priority.